# How to solve mysqli-mariaDB update fail, on a just inserted record

Tags: mysqli, synchronization, mariadb

Hi: I run stateless (REST) web services written in PHP7.0 OO-style, under Apache. They use mysqli to connect to mariaDB instance on AWS. We discovered a db synchronization issue, and not sure where the problem is or how to solve it.

1. client call to service 1 will insert a record, and return the autogenerated primary key retrieved by  $i_primary_key = $this->db->insert_id, post-successful insertion;
2. next client call will **use** that primary key to execute a service 2, which will UPDATE the record
3. since service 1 and 2 are separate https calls, they create their own connections, resources, etc.

The problem is that sometimes service 2 fails, complaining the record with such a primary key does not exist. Try again, or artificially delay calling service 2, after obtaining results from Service 1, and things work as they should.

How do I tell the mariaDB engine, or mysqli API to flush their cache after the insert? I am only guessing that the engine/connection in Service 1 has not yet made its resources available to its own internal server, hence other clients of the engine do not see the latest changes/data.

Any advice...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way for the "flush" not to have happened:  If the `INSERT` is in a transaction that is not committed.

To investigate, find out what value of `autocommit` is being used in "service 1".  If it is "on" (or "1"), then there is no way for the problem to occur.

If autocommit is off (0), the the code in service 1 failed to `COMMIT` the implicit transaction.  That is a user error.  I prefer, instead, to have explicit `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` statements.

Comment: Hi: autocommit is 1. As I wrote, these services mostly work. Just once in a while it doesn't. Actually it only occurs in our test environment, where we generate calls programatically bombarding the server... will try explicit START/COMMIT, it should help, but not sure we're solving the root cause, since autocommit already = 1. But thanks, will try.

Comment: Hi: start and commit did not help. the INSERT always works to the caller of service 1, because it does get the inserted key value. No errors. Never. The problem is that service 2 caller, even though he knows this key, when he executes service 2, update, the update will sometime fail with record does not exist. So, back to the original problem as described. There is a deeper problem at API-to_Engine level.

Comment: Is "service" really "server"?  And you have two machines (servers) in Replication?  If so, then say so; we need to discuss "critical reads" in replication.

Answer (score 0):

I found this reading up on mariaDB: 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#flush

flush

Description: Usually, MariaDB writes changes to disk after each SQL statement, and the operating system handles synchronizing (flushing) it to disk. If set to ON, the server will synchronize all changes to disk after each statement.
Commandline: --flush
Scope: Global
Dynamic: Yes
Data Type: boolean
Default Value: OFF

...So I'm going to set it to ON. Once I have results I'll update confirming it working...